# Windows Phone 8.1 UDP Multicast client

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, windows-phone-8.1, multicast

Trying an app for Windows Phone 8.1 and wondering how should I use DatagramSocket to send data to a multicast address. If I try to use ConnectAsync(HostName host) with some multicast address, ie. 239.0.0.1, I get a message "ConnectAcync() does not support multicast address".
How can I connect to multicast address and how can I send data to it?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `DatagramSocket.JoinMulticastGroup()`, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.joinmulticastgroup.aspx

UPDATE:

To just send a UDP message try:

```
IOutputStream outputStream = await datagramSocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(
    hostName,
    serviceName);
IBuffer buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello").AsBuffer();
uint bytesWritten = await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
```

Comment: I try this code:
`_mcastAddr = new HostName("239.0.0.1");
 _sock = new DatagramSocket();
 try
            {
                _sock.JoinMulticastGroup(_mcastAddr);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageDialog errorMsg = new MessageDialog("errorr");
                await errorMsg.ShowAsync();
            }` And I falls into catch section. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error? Invalid host name is a common error in Windows 8.1. Try selecting the network interface.

Comment: As I understand, JoinMulticastGroup() doesn't return any result as, for example, ConnectAsync() does. So if there is a way to find out an error occurred how can I figure this out?

Comment: If you get into the `catch` block, check the `Exception.HResult` value or the `Exception.Message`.

Comment: The error is: "Bind socket before joining a multicast group", Does it really necessary to bind a socket if I only want to SEND data to multicast group, not to receive it?